# Format specifier to print the whole integer array?

Tags: c, pointers, printf, c-strings

Printing character arrays (strings) can be done with very minimal effort of:
`printf("%s",array_name)`. So why not have something similar to print the integer datatype arrays?

If we have the code below:

```
int main()
{
  char C[10]={'a','b','c'};
  //to print the string here, we just do this thing below
  printf("%s",C);
}
```

We can print the contents in the whole character array just by using one printf statement, I found that cool after having run loops to do the same for integer data type arrays. So according to me, this `printf("%s", C)` would be interpreted as `%s -> want to print a string`, just passing the array name `C` , here decays to a pointer and the compiler somehow just goes to that location, reads one byte, dereferences it and sees that it (printf) hasn't found NULL yet, and again reads one byte, and so on. This idea sounded very cool to me and I got to thinking as to why do we not have something similar to print integer datatype arrays? Like some format specifier `%hey` and passing the array name would print the contents of the integer array? Just in this case, it would need to read 4 bytes and dereference it and move on until it finds some stop.
To put in code, it would be like replacing this below code

```
int main()
{
  int A[10]={1,2,3};
  //to print this array, we do this below
  for(i=0;i<9;i++)
  {
    printf("%d ", *(A+i));
  }
}
```

with this: `printf("%hey",A)` to print the whole integer array.

Comment: What is the question? Why doesn't C have it?

Comment: You can't, because the number of elements is in a way unknown. There's no sentinel value that indicates the end of the array. With some modifications and assumptions you could make something like that work, but it won't be very standard, and pretty niche.

Comment: How would `printf` know the array length?

Comment: @WeatherVane We could probably define that it should take two parameters for this specifier.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Right, yeah. "Why does C not have this?"

Comment: And what about the separater character? Sometimes you want a space, sometimes a comma, sometimes both - just make your own function.

Comment: @Floatoss Probably no specific *objective* reason. As said above, it will require two pieces of data (the pointer to the array and the length) to be passed along, which is different from the existing pattern. It will make the already quite overcomplicated function even more overcomplicated and error-prone.

Comment: I see, it does make sense that this would be very niche indeed. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1):

C does not have a generic way to pass an *array*.  Instead, when an array is passed, it is converted to the address of the array's first element, so to a `...` function like `printf(some_format, array_name)`, the array size is lost.  Passing only an array to `printf()`, even if the format was extended, code would need to pass size info also.

```
// Not doable in C - array size info lost
printf("some_extened_format", array_name);
```

---

Easy enough to write a helper function, maybe as:

```
void printf_int_array(const char *int_fmt, const char *separator_fmt,
    size_t n, const int a[n]) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (i > 0) {
      fputs(separator_fmt, stdout);
    }
    printf(int_fmt, a[i]);
  } 
}
```

We could use a macro to help us call it simply.

```
#define PRINT_INT_ARRAY_STD(A) \
    printf_int_array("%d", " ", sizeof(A)/sizeof((A)[0]), A)

// Usage
PRINT_INT_ARRAY_STD(some_int_array);
```

Consider there are a vast number of formats that one may want to print an *array* of `int`.

---

Details:

"Printing character arrays (strings) can be done with very minimal effort of: printf("%s",array_name)" is imprecise as is is loose with *character array* and *string*.

```
char C[10] = {'a','b','c'};
printf("%s", C);
```

That code does not print the array `C[]`.  Array `C` has 10 elements. and only `"abc"` is printed.  Code prints the *string*, not the array.

Instead, `"%s"` gets a pointer to the beginning of the array and prints until *null character* is encountered.

If the array C lacked a *null character*, `printf("%s", C);` would have been *undefined behavior*.

Arrays, either as `char`, `int`, ... do not certainly have a "end" value.  A *string* does.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that strings can not contain the embedded character '\0'. This character serves as a terminating character of a string.

On the other hand, other integer arrays can contain values equal to 0.

For example how are you going to output this integer array

```
int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

That is opposite to character arrays that contain strings other kinds of integer arrays (including also character arrays that do not contain strings) do not have a common adopted sentinel value.